# Fitting a straight line to a log-log curve

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, loglog

I have a plot with me which is logarithmic on both the axes. I have pyplot's `loglog` function to do this. It also gives me the logarithmic scale on both the axes.

Now, using numpy I fit a straight line to the set of points that I have. However, when I plot this line on the plot, I cannot get a straight line. I get a curved line. 
[image: The blue line is the supposedly "straight line". It is not getting plotted straight. I want to fit a straight line to the curve plotted by red dots]

The blue line is the supposedly "straight line". It is not getting plotted straight. I want to fit this straight line to the curve plotted by red dots

Here is the code I am using to plot the points:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
fp=open("word-rank.txt","r")
a=[]
b=[]

for line in fp:
    string=line.strip().split()
    a.append(float(string[0]))
    b.append(float(string[1]))

coefficients=numpy.polyfit(b,a,1)
polynomial=numpy.poly1d(coefficients)
ys=polynomial(b)
print polynomial
plt.loglog(b,a,'ro')
plt.plot(b,ys)
plt.xlabel("Log (Rank of frequency)")
plt.ylabel("Log (Frequency)")
plt.title("Frequency vs frequency rank for words")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Isn't it simply that you are plotting the straight line on a logarithmic scale?

Comment: Ya, it is. But how do I plot it using matplotlib such that it is perfectly coverst the line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your linear fit is not performed on the same data as shown in the loglog-plot.

Make a and b numpy arrays like this

```
a = numpy.asarray(a, dtype=float)
b = numpy.asarray(b, dtype=float)
```

Now you can perform operations on them. What the loglog-plot does, is to take the logarithm to base 10 of both a and b. You can do the same by

```
logA = numpy.log10(a)
logB = numpy.log10(b)
```

This is what the loglog plot visualizes. Check this by ploting both logA and logB as a regular plot. Repeat the linear fit on the log data and plot your line in the same plot as the logA, logB data.

```
coefficients = numpy.polyfit(logB, logA, 1)
polynomial = numpy.poly1d(coefficients)
ys = polynomial(b)
plt.plot(logB, logA)
plt.plot(b, ys)
```

Comment: should `ys = polynomial(logB)` ?

Answer (score 12):

To better understand this problem, let's first talk about plain ol' linear regression (the `polyfit` function, in this case, is your linear regression algorithm).

---

Suppose you have a set of data points (x,y), shown below:

[image: Linear regression diagram]

You want to create a model that predicts `y` as a function of `x`, so you use linear regression. That uses the model:

`y = mx + b`

and computes the values of `m` and `b` that best predict your data, using some linear algebra.

Next, you use your model to predict values of y as a function of x. You do this by picking a set of values for x (think linspace) and computing the corresponding values of y. Plotting these (x,y) pairs gives you your regression line.

---

Now, let's talk about logarithmic regression. In this case, we still have two variables, y versus x, and we are still interested in their relationship, i.e., being able to predict `y` given `x`. The only difference is, now `y` and `x` happen to be logarithms of two other variables, which I'll call `log(F)` and `log(R)`. Thus far, this is nothing more than a simple change of name.

[image: Log regression diagram]

The linear regression also works the same way. You're still regressing y versus x. The linear regression algorithm doesn't care that `y` and `x` are actually `log(F)` and `log(R)` - it makes no difference to the algorithm.

The last step is a little bit different - and this is where you're getting tripped up in your plot above. What you're doing is computing

`F = m R + b`

but this is incorrect, because the relationship between `F` and `R` is not linear. (That's why you're using a log-log plot.)

Instead, you should compute

`log(F) = m log(R) + b`

If you transform this (raise 10 to the power of both sides and rearrange), you get

`F = c R^m`

where `c = 10^b`. This is the relationship between `F` and `R`: it is a power law relationship. (Power law relationships are what log-log plots are best at.)

In your code, you're using A and B when calling `polyfit`, but you should be using `log(A)` and `log(B)`.

Comment: shouldn't np.log(A) == np.log10(A) ?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers offer great explanations and a solution. However I would like to propose a solution that helped myself a lot and maybe will help you as well.

Another simple way of writing a line fit for log-log scale is the function `powerfit` in the code below. It takes in the original `x` and `y` data and by using a number of new x-points you can get a straight line on log-log scale. In the current case the values `xnew` are the same as `x` (which are both `b`).

The advantage of defining new x-coordinates is that you can get as few or as many points of the powerfitted line for whatever purpose you might need them.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math


def powerfit(x, y, xnew):
    """line fitting on log-log scale"""
    k, m = np.polyfit(np.log(x), np.log(y), 1)
    return np.exp(m) * xnew**(k)


fp=open("word-rank.txt","r")
a=[]
b=[]

for line in fp:
    string=line.strip().split()
    a.append(float(string[0]))
    b.append(float(string[1]))

ys = powerfit(b, a, b)

plt.loglog(b,a,'ro')
plt.plot(b,ys)
plt.xlabel("Log (Rank of frequency)")
plt.ylabel("Log (Frequency)")
plt.title("Frequency vs frequency rank for words")
plt.show()
```